# Accessing child product which has been added to cart

Tags: magento-1.8, blocks, bundled-product

I can't seem to find a solution for this issue where I have bundle parent products with child products and need to display the selected child product's attributes at the cart, such as dates and times.

I've had a look at a few posts on how to do this (more or less), including the following:

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
foreach ($session->getQuote()->getAllItems() as $item)
{
    // Load the configured product options
    $options = $item->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->getOrderOptions($item->getProduct());
     // Just dumping array content
     echo "<pre>"; var_dump($options);
}
```

This gives me a ["bundle_options"] array with some information like option_id, label, value, however it doesn't give me a product ID i could use to access the attributes I need.

I've also looked at the checkout/cart_item_renderer block but can't really see anything here I can use either.

Grateful for any pointers on how to do this, pretty new to magento!